# html direct link download not working with different file encodings

Tags: html, download, hyperlink, href

I'm editing a site created by another developer.
Trying different ways to download some files I noticed this:

I took a random file and put the file in the root folder of the site

1) renaming the file "a.exe",
   if I browse to "www.mysite.com/a.exe" starts the file download.

2) renaming the file "a.pdf",
   if I browse to "www.mysite.com/a.pdf" browser tries to open the pdf.

3) renaming the file "a.txt",
   if I browse to "www.mysite.com/a.txt" starts the file download.

4) renaming the file "a.jpg",
   if I browse to "www.mysite.com/a.jpg" browser tries to display the image.

5) renaming the file "a.apk",
   if I browse to "www.mysite.com/a.apk" server responds with "404 - File or directory not found.".

but .... why? the file is the same, and is always in the same folder, why suddenly seems to "disappear"?

the previous developer had designed a server-side workarounds to make it possible to download apk file.

but I can not believe that to download a file I can not simply write

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/a.apk"> DOWNLOAD </ a>
```

because it works with all file types except with the apk file...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution! If we want to download an apk file we have to tell the site how it should behave.
to do this add to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>

    <staticContent>

        <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />

    </staticContent>

</system.webServer>
```

later simply build a link in this way:

```
<a href="myappPath.apk">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

that's all!

Answer (score 2):

The server that hosts the website probably does not know this file type extenstion (MIME types). Every extension is declared in the server. With these declarations you can allow and deny file types to be access via the internet.
You'll probably have to add the file extension to the server.

the MIME declaration for APK is **application/vnd.android.package-archive**

Comment: do you know how can I do that? I thought there was a chance to write something somewhere, for example in the web.config or in similar configuration files..

Comment: What kind of server are you using? IIS / Apache?

Comment: you need to alter the web server config file for reliable results. eg. apache has a file `mimetype.conf` which contains the mapping between extensions and mime types.

Comment: @Ben Van Hees I'm using IIS

Comment: 2 options: first option is to add this to your web.config: <configuration><system.webServer><staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" /></staticContent></system.webServer></configuration>
Second option: Open IIS, expand tree to your website, open "Mime Types", click Add, Fill-in Extension(.apk) & Mime Type (application/vnd.android.package-archive) and click OK. This website now always knows apk files. If you want this on whole IIS, do this action on your ROOT node in IIS (COMPUTERNAME)

Answer (score 0):

Web Server, client os and user agent interact in determining the content type of downloaded resources. the web server sends http headers telling the client what the sent content represents and may add headers by which it specifies whether to save the content as a file and may suggest a file name. however, user settings in the browser may override this. the browser's and os-wide associations of file extensions with content types and/or with actions may interfere too. a file extension would be the end of the url's path part (this holds even for dynamically created resources).

if you do not need browser integration have a look at the command line tools `curl`or `wget`, where you can expressly specify to save the downloaded data under a given file name.

eg. (linux; for windows replace all single quotes with double quotes; you don't need user/password for unprotected resources, obviously):

```
wget --no-cache --no-check-certificate --no-proxy 
     --output-document='<target_file_name>'
     --auth-no-challenge --http-user='<user>' --http-password='<pw>' '<url>'
```